# Cut verbosity of try-catch block in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a lot of network calls and try-catch blocks are pretty verbose, what the best way to cut on this boilerplate?
I would like to replace sth like that

```
  Future<Something> getSomething(String id) async {
    try {
      return await _api.getSomething(id);
    } on DioError catch (error) {
      return Future.error(error.formattedMessage);
    }
  }
```

to be able to call sth like

```
  Future<Something> getSomething(String id) async {
    networkCall { _api.getSomething(id); }
  }
```

Is there construction in Dart that will let me achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no language feature that does what you're looking for.

If you just want the function to complete with the `DioError` and don't need to create a new exception, you can just remove the try/catch block and let the caller handle the error.

If you do want to do some processing on a specific type of exception frequently, you can always write a wrapper method to do that:

```dart
Future<T> handleDioError<T>(Future<T> Function() f) async {
  try {
    return await f();
  } on DioError catch(e) {
    return Future.error(error.formattedMessage);
  }
}
```

Which you'd use like this:

```dart
Future<Something> getSomething(String id) async {
  return await handleDioError(() => _api.getSomething(id));
}
```